# Displaying student absent dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Here is the table I want to display:

```
   tblAttendance table
    CustomerId
    Id
    Attendence 
    Date
    and
    tblStudent 
    CustomerId
    Name
```

Now I want to search by from to date and want absent date.
How can I achieve this?

I tried below code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spExceptDate

AS
declare @StartDate DATE, @EndDate DATE
set @StartDate = '2020-02-15';
set @EndDate = '2020-02-25';
BEGIN


 SELECT CustomerId,FirstName+' '+LastName,Date,Attendance 
FROM
[dbo].[tblAttendance] att
LEFT JOIN
[dbo].[tblStudent] st
ON att.CustomerId = st.Code

EXCEPT

 SELECT CustomerId,FirstName+' '+LastName,Date,Attendance 
FROM
[dbo].[tblAttendance] att
LEFT JOIN
[dbo].[tblStudent] st
ON att.CustomerId = st.Code
where att.Date>='2020-02-15' and att.Date<='2020-02-25'

END
GO
```

i want date for which student absend

Comment: the code is in SQL and not C#

Comment: yes in sql......

Comment: please change the title and tags. remove c# and keep only sql. what is the table structure of `tblAttendance`?

Comment: Edit the question add sample data & desired result would helpful & Explain why your code doesn't work ? What error you get ?

Comment: id,attendance,date

Comment: Try like  this `WHERE att.Date BETWEEN  '2020-02-15' and '2020-02-25'` refer to this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/between-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#d-using-between-with-datetime-values)

Comment: What kind of data stored in column `Attendence`? is it 1 or 0?

Comment: P for present....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you need is list of possible dates between `From` and `To`

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2020-02-15',
        @EndDate DATE = '2020-02-25' ;

--Create a CTE to get all dates between from and to (you should filter holidays and weekends)
WITH SchoolCalendar (WorkingDay)
AS (SELECT @StartDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, WorkingDay)
    FROM SchoolCalendar 
    WHERE WorkingDay< @EndDate
   )

--Use the CTE to determine the Absense records
SELECT st.Code CustomerId, st.FirstName+' '+st.LastName Name,st.WorkingDay Date, COALESCE(Attendance,'A')  Attendance
FROM (SELECT * from SchoolCalendar, tblStudent) st
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[tblAttendance] att ON att.Date = st.WorkingDay AND att.CustomerId = st.Code
WHERE st.WorkingDay>=@StartDate and st.WorkingDay<=@EndDate
ORDER BY st.Code, st.WorkingDay
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need only one query if you want to fetch only absent student names from the given date range

```
SELECT CustomerId,FirstName+' '+LastName,Date,Attendance 
FROM [dbo].[tblAttendance] att
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[tblStudent] st ON att.CustomerId = st.Code
WHERE att.Date>='2020-02-15' and att.Date<='2020-02-25' AND att.Attendance <> 'P'
                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: can i get both present and absent result in single table?

Comment: and i do not store absent in table

Comment: then just removed last condition from WHERE clause

Comment: Yes, I think you just have to remove the last bit on the where condition in Jaydip's answer.

Comment: but i didnt store absent then how can i get absent date

Comment: now i am losing customerid,and name when student is absent